# Notation in transistor circuits

Tags: transistors, circuit-analysis, analog

These two figures(below) are from book Microelectronics circuits by Sedra/Smith.

I have two doubt regarding notation used in this book (or may be in general also)

[image]

1.in this figure(1) why there are two arrows ( most of the times only one arrow is there) pointing towards 10v and in general what  arrows indicate (or its significance)

[image]

2.in this figure (2)

how to judge  (method?) whether  emmiter terimnal  Re2  of Q2 transistor is connected to 15v terminal of Rc1 (Q1 transistor)

```
 or
```

grounded collector terminal Rc2 (Q2 transistor)?

Comment: They indicate a positive terminal of a voltage source +10V in the first case and +15V in the second case.

Comment: sigh... your computer has a screenshot functionality. I can't believe it's 2020 and we still have to tell people that it's better to just push a button on their computer instead of taking a photo with a camera...

Comment: @MarcusMüller I agree with [this](https://i.imgur.com/LBT2Jr7.jpg)

Comment: @SpehroPefhany I have an idea how to 1-up this – but it would take me dusting off my old 800x600-era CRT and reviving the battery in my first digital camera, and finding a SmartMedia card.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Publications like this use graphic drawing tools to make these illustrations. They don't necessarily use any kind of electronic CAD tool, so there's no checking other than human beings inspecting the illustration.

In the first figure, the double-arrow appears to be... a mistake that got past the proofreader. A single arrow is enough to indicate the power connection.

In the second figure, you can safely assume that all the upward-facing arrows are connected to the same voltage, that is, +15V. The illustrator either got lazy, or didn't want to clutter the figure with three +15V labels.

In an actual schematic drawn in a CAD tool, each power connection would be associated with a specific network (power domain). Common power connection symbols include the arrow, bar, or circle.

Ground symbols show the zero-volts reference for the drawing. These can have variations to distinguish between power, signal, and earth grounds.

Comment: I like your comment: ：double-arrow appears to be... a mistake that got past the proofreader“. I have just started reading a similar book by Jaeger (sorry, I can't spell). I saw google has Sedra next Jaeger. I need to start skimming Sedga to see if it was worth reading.

Answer (score 3):

The arrows toward a marked voltage indicate a connection (that is not shown) to a voltage rail. It is typical in modern schematics to show positive voltages at the top and negative voltages at the bottom. Very simple.

In the second case, the duplicated arrows are assumed to be connected to the same voltage source since no others are shown. If there were two in the same schematic they should all be individually labeled (or somehow grouped) in order to avoid any ambiguity.

The arrows shown with the current name beside them indicate the name assigned to that current and also the assumed direction of the current. If the value turns out to be negative, then the current is flowing in the opposite direction of the arrow.

Comment: Your answer is good and newbie friendly. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

The equivalent circuit for this schematice:

[image]

will look like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fi8eS2.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Which is equivalent with:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fEDAmv.png)</sup>

Comment: Can you please tell me how you do the transformation, is it by a deep learning tool?